Epos2Printer can print only once in ipadOS 17.1.2 and 17.5.1
I am using Epson TM-30II-S printer to print from my app via bluetooth connection.
I used this latest sdk ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.29.1 and can print once. The app has to be restarted in order to be able to print again.
I found this  and it look like as same as my problem.
but I got the problem with approved answer. I have never get called onPtrReceive() function even through be implemented by Epos2PtrReceiveDelegate. Is this bug of SDK? (Base on current update note, max support is iPadOS 17.0. So may be 17.x.x is still need to fixed?)
func onDiscovery(_ deviceInfo: Epos2DeviceInfo!) {
        print("Found epson printer: \(deviceInfo.deviceName ?? ""), \(String(describing: deviceInfo.target)).")
        guard let printer = Epos2Printer(printerSeries: EPOS2_TM_M30II.rawValue, lang: EPOS2_MODEL_JAPANESE.rawValue)
        else { return }
        
        printer.setReceiveEventDelegate(self)
        printer.addFeedLine(1)
        printer.addTextFont(2)
        printer.addTextSize(2, height: 2)
        printer.addText("text\n")
        printer.addText("text2")
        printer.addCut(EPOS2_CUT_FEED.rawValue)
        
        let status = printer.connect(deviceInfo.target, timeout: Int(EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT))
        print(">>>status", status)
        printer.beginTransaction()
        let result = printer.sendData(Int(EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT))
        printer.endTransaction()
        if result != EPOS2_SUCCESS.rawValue {
            print("failed")
        } else {
            print("success")
        }
    }


func onPtrReceive(_ printerObj: Epos2Printer!, code: Int32, status: Epos2PrinterStatusInfo!, printJobId: String!) {
        print(">>>receive")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async(execute: {
            printerObj.endTransaction()
            printerObj.disconnect()
            printerObj.clearCommandBuffer()
            printerObj.setReceiveEventDelegate(nil)
        })
    }

It should be get called onPtrReceive() function (It's look like printer disconnect process only work here). After that printer can connect again and printing will be success for next time.

Finally I got this, printer variable inside of function need to assign to instance variable of class. Or not, it's not remain on memory and delegate not work.
`
private var epsonPrinter: Epos2Printer?
guard let printer = Epos2Printer(printerSeries: EPOS2_TM_M30II.rawValue, lang: EPOS2_MODEL_JAPANESE.rawValue)
else { return }
self.epsonPrinter = printer
printer.setReceiveEventDelegate(self)
printer.connect(deviceInfo.target, timeout: Int(EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT))
self.sentPrintData(device: deviceInfo, printer: printer)
`
